# Spring Data JPA - JPQL update query - printing out unupdated value

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Trying out doing update Queries in Spring Data JPA. In my test method (see below) I'm saving one student with firstName="Bill" and lastName="Smith". How can it be that I'm getting "Bill" printed out to the console (very last line), given that studentRespository.findByFirstName("John") actually gives a list with one member?
Any help appreciated...

```js
    @Modifying(flushAutomatically = true)
    @Transactional
    @Query("update Student s set s.firstName = ?1 where s.lastName= ?2")
    public void updateFirstNameByLastName(String firstName, String lastName)
```

```js
    @Test
    public void updateStudentFirstNameByLastName() {
        studentRepository.save(student); //student.firstName="Bill", student.lastName="Smith"
        studentRepository.updateFirstNameByLastName("John", "Smith");
        List<Student> studentList = studentRepository.findByFirstName("John"); // size 1
        System.out.println(studentList.get(0).getFirstName()); // "Bill"
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the *JPA’s entity lifecycle states* save() method may not write your changes to database immediately.

Since we use **@Modifying** in update query, this triggers the query annotated to the method as an updating query instead of a selecting one.

Reason for above issue is, when we save(), the persistence context of this with outdated entities may still there after the execution of the modifying query. `EntityManager` do not automatically clear it.  If you wish the `EntityManager` to be cleared/flushed automatically, you can set the **@Modifying** annotation’s *clearAutomatically* and *flushAutomatically* attribute to true. Check this official doc [Modifying Queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries).

[Annotation Type Modifying](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Modifying.html)

***clearAutomatically(true/false)*** - Defines whether we should clear the underlying persistence context after executing the modifying query. (Default -false)

***flushAutomatically(true/false)*** - Defines whether we should flush the underlying persistence context before executing the modifying query. (Default -false)

Add this ***@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)*** to the `updateFirstNameByLastName` method as below.

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
@Query("update Student s set s.firstName = ?1 where s.lastName= ?2")
public void updateFirstNameByLastName(String firstName, String lastName)
```

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth answer - now prints out the correct result!

Comment: @LorenzMueller Glad to hear it worked. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your test didn't commit anything to the database

Try to add @Rollback(value = false) to the test class may help

[image: Spring boot with JUnit 5 test]

Comment: Hey, tried that out! When I run verify now, the insertions done one individual tests are not rolled back before executing a new one. However, it would still print out the unupdated value as above. Setting "clearAutomatically=true" as property of @Modifying does the trick, as in DevThiman's answer.